# Smooth Edges In Segmentation

Tags: photoshop, image-segmentation, cvat

I am working on project in which i have to do segmentation masking. Now problem is that exported masked image should have 2 things.

**NOTE: Please download both images for better understanding my problem**

1. Only 2 Colors.
2. No Jagged Edges.

**Tools Used**:

1. Cvat
2. Photopea ( for Reducing Colors )
3. Pixspy ( for checking how many colors image have )

If i achieve 1 ( means if i reduce color ) than for sure jagged edges will appear. because mask is png and if you remove colors from jagged edges than it is obvious that all shades which given illusion of image smoothing will disappear. and if i go with no jagged edges than i will get thousands of colors in image.

**Image with Smooth edges but many colors around 12k**

[image: Image with Smooth edges but many colors around 12k]

**Image with Jagged edges but limited colors only 2**

[image]

**How can i achieve both of the things on same time for my mask.**

Comment: What is the script you are currently using? If your question isn't about scripts, it is off topic here.

Comment: VLL i have updated the question with tools i am using.

Comment: This is just example...real images have much more complex structure...repeating these steps will be problematic for me

Comment: Lookup Anti-aliasing and learn that what you are asking is definitionally impossible